# R sqldf find the second largest

Tags: r, sqldf

I have a dataframe  data like this

```
data
  id time var1
1  a    3    0
2  a    2    2
3  a    1    3
4  b    3    2
5  b    4    6
```

I want to get the second largest time row of each id like this:

```
data2
  id time var1
1  a    2    2
2  b    3    2
```

I try use sqldf

```
sqldf("select * from data order by time desc limit 2,1 group by id")
```

but I got an Error:

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: near "group": syntax error
```

I also try:

```
select max(time),* from data where time not in(select max(time) from data group by id) group by id
```

but I only got a result, I can't get the right answer.

Thanks !

Comment: Is it required to use `sqldf` or would you be interested in other methods?

Comment: The dplyr looks sort of like the SQL: `df %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(desc(time)) %>% slice(2)`

Comment: dplyr it works,thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking the maximum among the rows with values less than the maximum for that id:

```
sqldf("select id, max(time) time, var1 
       from data a
       where time < (select max(b.time) 
                     from data b 
                     where b.id = a.id)
       group by id")
```